# How to set the background image of a button in java swing

Tags: java, swing

I want to change the background image of a JButton in swing,
The method :
*Button.setIcon (),*
Set’s the icon only not the background,
Is there a **easy** way to do that?

Comment: See [JButton background image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17110315/jbutton-background-image)

Comment: So how is the background changed in the example?  (it’s the icon)

Comment: was adding that comment for @peter.petrov as he was unable to post it as a comment, have added answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easy way use SynthLookAndFeel as described [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/synthExample.html) or you could go with creating a class that extends JButton and provide a new implementation of paintComponent(Graphics g)

Answer (score 5):

You can still use `setIcon` but you will need to set the alignment to make the text appear over the image

```
button.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);
```

Answer (score 4):

One option is to subclass JButton, override paintComponent() method and paint the icon there.

Comment: That's a lot of work for functionality that already exists.  Simply set the icon's alignment to center and the text alignments to center as outlined by Reimeus

Comment: Setting the icon and the text alignment will work but the button won't have the same visual cues as a regular button, that is, the background won't highlight on mouseover/click. For this reason, you probably will have to revert to using paintComponent() and implement your own logic to render the background slightly differently on these events.