# Windows Calculator Buttons

Tags: java, calculator

I want to get long button like the '=' & '0' buttons on the windows calculator:

[image: The windows calculator].

Please any one help me.

Also i need to modify this same code, is there way do that from  GRIDLAYOUT?

```
import java.awt.*;

class Cal{
    Cal(){
        Frame f=new Frame();
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setSize(350,500);
        f.setTitle("Nano Cal");

        Panel p1=new Panel();
        p1.setBackground(Color.lightGray);

        Panel p2=new Panel();
        p2.setBackground(Color.gray);

        BorderLayout br=new BorderLayout();
        f.add(p1,br.NORTH);
        f.add(p2,br.CENTER);

        TextField t1=new TextField(57);
        p1.add(t1);

        Button b1=new Button("MC");
        Button b2=new Button("MR");
        Button b3=new Button("MS");
        Button b4=new Button("M+");
        Button b5=new Button("M-");
        Button b6=new Button("<-");
        Button b7=new Button("CE");
        Button b8=new Button("C");
        Button b9=new Button("±");
        Button b10=new Button("√");
        etc.

        p2.add(b1);
        p2.add(b2);
        p2.add(b3);
        p2.add(b4);
        p2.add(b5);
        p2.add(b6);
        p2.add(b7);
        p2.add(b8);
        p2.add(b9);
        p2.add(b10);

        GridLayout gr=new GridLayout(6,5,5,5);
        p2.setLayout(gr);

        MenuBar mb=new MenuBar();
        f.setMenuBar(mb);
        Menu    m1=new  Menu("View");
        Menu    m2=new  Menu("Edit");
        Menu    m3=new  Menu("Help");
        mb.add(m1);
        mb.add(m2);
        mb.add(m3);

        MenuItem mview=new MenuItem("Copy");
        MenuItem mview2=new MenuItem("Paste");
        m1.add(mview);
        m1.add(mview2);



    }   
}

class testCal{
    public static void main(String sr[]){

        Cal c = new Cal();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can design your own buttons.You can use images on buttons by using setIcon().This will help you design a calculator with enriched graphical look and feel.See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21270656/how-to-set-the-background-image-of-a-button-in-java-swing

Comment: See how to use [GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html). And why are you using AWT and not [Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/)?

Comment: also, the font size of the windows buttons looks around 2x bigger.

Answer (score 1):

The entire point of GridLayout is to make things equal sizes.  It sounds like you want to be using another layout manager such as GridBagLayout or MigLayout (not built into Java, see http://www.miglayout.com) instead.

Comment: can i resize a button on this?

Comment: Yes, either of those layout managers will let you resize buttons (or any other component).  Personally I find MigLayout to be the easier of the two to use.  See the quick start PDF for MigLayout at http://www.miglayout.com/QuickStart.pdf or the Swing demo (shows both what it can do and what source code to use to do it) at http://www.migcalendar.com/miglayout/swingdemoapp.jnlp